# how to navigate UItabbarviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4.5, navigationcontroller

I Have a viewcontroller and tabbarviewcontroller.
I du have the connection between viewcontroller and tabbarviewcontroller.
**Example: If I click on a picture inside a button of viewcontroller then the tabbarviewcontroller got opened.
but I need to back from tab1 or tab2 with a navigationcontroller.**
what is the easiest way and efficient way to do it in iOS?

Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using storyboard just put a button on the tab bar1 or 2 navigation bar and connect it In IB to push back to whichever view you want. If you are using xib fe then two options. You can programically add a back button to the view did load or create a button action and push it to the view from there. I'm at work now so I can't give a code snippet example but if you need one I can do that tonight when I get back home.

Hope this helps

Adrian